# Proving $3^n+2(17^n)$ can't be a perfect square for all positive integers n.

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

I think I have a valid proof of this question, but as my textbook doesn't provide an answer, I would appreciate some clarification.

Let $f(n)=3^n+2(17^n)$, and the question asks to show $f(n)$ is never a perfect square for positive integers n.

Using quadratic residues, we see:

$x^2(mod 5)$ is either $ 0, 1, 4 $ only.

Taking $f(n)$ and breaking it up into $3^n$ and $2(17^n)$, we can see the following modulo-periodic sequences taking each part $mod5$

The sequence of $3^n (mod5)$ is: $ 3, 4, 2, 1 ,3...$, with a period of $4$, for positive integers $n$.

The sequence of $2(17^n)$ $(mod5)$ is : $4, 3, 1, 2, 4...$, with a period of 4.

Hence, $f(n)$ $(mod 5)$ is equal to the sum of each corresponding element in each sequence, taken $(mod 5)$.

This produces the sequence: $2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2.....$

Hence, $f(n)$ $(mod5)$ leaves remainders of $2$ and $3$ only, and as a square $(mod5)$ leaves remainders of $0, 1, 4$ only, $f(n)$ can never be a perfect square.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks good, excellent method.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which textbook has this rather nice question?

Comment: UKMT "Introduction to Number Theory".It was a question on the British Maths Olympiad round 1 in 1991.

Answer (score 4):

Your method is excellent.

My immediate "first try" was to look at the result $\bmod 8$, since the number is clearly odd and all odd squares are $1 \bmod 8$.

So for positive $n$ we have $3^n\equiv \{1,3\} \bmod 8$ and $17^n\equiv 1 \bmod 8$ obviously, so $f(n)\equiv \{3,5\} \bmod 8$ which is never square.